# dynamically add route to script src on an html page

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, server, src

i want to dynamically add route to script src on an html page.
for example,

```
<script src="../../../library/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

when i use web server and load this code, not working. maybe it should put web server url prefix. so i want to change below.

```
<script src="mySite/../../../library/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

or,
other things that root-relative path set?

Answer (score 3):

Use below JavaScript code:

```
    var scr = document.createElement('script');
    var myurl = 'http://example.com/myjavascript.js'
    scr.setAttribute('src',myurl);

    document.head.appendChild(scr);
```

or you can create a function like this:

```
function addMyScript(url) {
  var scr = document.createElement('script');
  scr.setAttribute('src', url);
  document.head.appendChild(src);
}
```

you can dynamically decide your url and call the function by passing it as a parameter:

```
addMyScript('http://example.com/myjavascript.js');
```

Comment: Oh I didn't thought about that. Ok, you must get the "myUrl" from somewhere right at the beginning of the first html you render.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be achieved by html or javascript only. You need at least a framework which is able to "render" your html before it is send to your browser and replace "mySite".

Example in JSF 2.x it would look like this:

```
<link href="#{request.contextPath}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Or Thymeleaf:

```
<a th:href="@{/order/list}">
```

If you want to develop for example a one page site, where the content is replaced dynamically by ajax, then you need at least one page which is dynamically created by one of this frameworks.